# Yolov8 does not use cuda

Tags: python, pytorch, yolov8

I installed cuda.
torch.cuda.is_available() returns true.
torch.cuda.get_device_name(0) returns NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU.
I would like to ask for help on how to get the model to use VRAM and GPU.
CUDA 12.1

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')
model.to("cuda")
results = model.predict(source="videoplayback.mp4", show=True, device="cuda")
print(results.cuda())
```

Comment: How do you know it's not using CUDA?

Comment: The gpu load does not reach 15%, but the cpu load is over 50% and the RAM is over 90%.

Comment: I suppose CUDA is used in this example, the yolov8n (nano) model is a too-light model to seriously load a GPU. On the other hand,  you are not using streaming mode for inference on a video file, so inference results for the full video file are accumulating in RAM. In the streaming mode, the model will return a memory-efficient Python generator of Results objects and RAM will be not overloaded. https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/predict/#key-features-of-predict-mode